Is there a source for jumping straight to techiyat hametim without having to die?
BH
Hi, correct me if I'm wrong.  I heard there are two possibile outcomes that will get a person to techiyat hametim.  One is the person dies, goes to Gan Eden bezrat Hashem, and then gets resurrected for techiyat hametim.  The second is a person doesn't die and just jumps straight to techiyat hametim. Is the last option true? If yes, what is the source of this second option?

According to Ramchal, even those alive at techiyas hameisim will have to die and be resurrected.

What does the second one even mean?

If you aren't dead how would you be resurrected from being dead? That makes no sense

Sefer אמונות ודעות סוף מאמר ז of Rav Sadia Goan mentions the second approach. Of course, there are those who disagree with this.

The Lubavitcher Rebbe explains why some earlier sources have disagreements about this subject.
Essentially, it is because the Zohar had not yet been discovered.
The Rebbe explains that the Zohar, Shemot, page 208b explains that prior to the time of the beginning of the resurrection, death comes by way of the Angel of Death. That means the soul ascending to the World of Souls (which is also called the World to Come because the soul go there from this world after death).
Once the period for resurrection (which is called Keitz HaYamin like is mentioned in Daniel 12:13) has arrived, death will only come directly from G-d and will be followed with immediate resurrection for such an individual.
A discussion of this can be found in Sha’arei Geulah, volume 2, pages 300-301.

IIRC it says in בלע המות this death can be metaphorical.

@shmosel If you read the notes, the Rebbe points to some objections that were raised in that direction. It is not “Olam HaTechiyah” yet. It is still “Days of Moshiach” when resurrection begins. That is 5794 (2034). 206 years before the year 6000. The Rebbe says “death” will be like the blink of an eye and similar to the idea that the Baal Shem Tov chose to experience “return to the dust” for completeness, not by necessity. He could have ascended alive like Chanoch and Eliyahu.
